# Как правильно минимизировать код

Tags: laravel

Есть два проекта на laravel, нужно с одного сайта получить информацию на другой

На первом сайте сделал API, на втором нужно получить

Получаю так:

```
$unitsAllGet = file_get_contents('url api');
$unitsAll = json_decode($unitsAllGet);
if($unitsAll->rez) {
...дальше идут разные проверки
```

Данный код повторяется много раз в разных местах, как правильное его минимизировать, чтобы не повторять?

Создать функцию в моделе, добавить в нее данный код и в нужно месте вызывать?

```
$modal = new ModalName();
$unitsAll = $modal->function_name();
```

Comment: Это скорее `Action`...